# is it possible to obtain the structure of a firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to know if it is possible to save the structure of an existing Firebase database.
I downloaded the json with the data contained, but I would like a scheme similar to the ER scheme, or at least the structure of the tables with the type of fields.
Is it possible to do it in some way?

Comment: Depends on the structure of the JSON in question. You could create CSV files but you would have to parse the data to distinguish the tables and rows. Otherwise, if the structure is relatively simple, you can find programs that will convert for you.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database (and Firestore, can't tell which one you mean) are both schemaless, NoSQL databases.  They are not relational databases.  There is no inherent structure to their contents other than what you, as the designer and coder, impose on them.  They could be highly structured or loosely structured.  The database system itself doesn't really care what you put into it.  You just need to make sure that your queries are satisfied by whatever you do there.

Since there is no inherent structure or relationships, it's not really possible to "export" such definition, since it's only defined by what you choose to actually do with it.